# Convert javascript path to windows path in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I have a string that contains a path that is formatted like this:

/C/Users/heresh/Desktop/output/2016

How can I convert this path to a windows path:

C:\Users\heresh\Desktop\output\2016

I know I should use: path.replace() but I cant get it to work.

I have tried the following and a million other methods.

```
var dirPathWin = name.replace("/", "\")
```

Comment: Just to give more info on why it errors, `replace` only replaces the first occurrence of a string. Secondly it will error because \ is used to escape characters. So in your replace you've escaped the quote leaving an open string. `.replace("/", "\\")` would successfully replace the first occurrence. You may find [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) a useful read.

Comment: Thank you very much for this additional info. Its great information that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try **RegEx** to replace the string.

```
var dirPathWin = name.replace(/\//g, '\\');
```

```js
function convUrl(){
    var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465317/convert-javascript-path-to-windows-path-in-acrobat/40465489#40465489'

    var converted = url.replace(/\//g,'\\');
    document.getElementById('conv').innerHTML = converted;
}
convUrl();
```

```html
<strong>URL</strong>
<br />
<span id='url'>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465317/convert-javascript-path-to-windows-path-in-acrobat/40465489#40465489</span>

<br />
<br />
<strong>Converted</strong>
<br />
<span id='conv'></span>
```